# Samsung A51 suddenly turns off

Tags: samsung, hardware, power-on

My brand new Samsung A51 Telenor phone turns off after 1-2h in screen lock. We gave it to service, but they said there are no problems. But the phone still powers off when it is not used less and in it is in the lock screen. Does anybody have similar problem?

We also did factory reset, softer reset, cleared the cache, but no use.

Comment: The service lies, as usual. Btw, it is very unlikely that they would be some official repair, it is more likely that they are only some company contract, having zero access to any phone documentation or any specific skills to fix the phone. Their real job is to handle similar complaints like yours, but without doing anything (and without needing to pay back the money or giving you a new phone).

Comment: Btw, I think most likely the battery is bad in your phone, however your only way to check this, if you buy a new battery and try it. If the problem remains, then you will have two good batteries with a bad phone.

Comment: thank you, i give to service again and tell them if no new phone please don't bother to return it to me. :) we will see

Comment: It won't work, they won't give it you another phone. They would need to buy it from the producer, exactly like you. If you complain strongly, they accept the phone "for repair", then they do nothing and they give it back as "it is repaired". It worths a try, but the best what you can do if you help the googlers of the future by posting your complains to the internet. And, as you buy your next phone, google for it - maybe others did the same before you...

Comment: You have a *very little* chance that also they will try a battery replace. But even this would mean that they need to work. Phones can not be repaired, some parts can be replaced but that is all. The rules to handle customer complaints were created for washing machines or for refrigerators, these can be repaired.

Comment: yes i think you right i get sms that phone work in bound of specification and that noting wrong, so i think that this will not be easy at all. thank you in any way. maybe i can try to root it and put some other rom or custom rom?

Comment: If it is a battery problem, or a problem of the battery management hardware, it won't work. I think it is the most likely. In your place I would buy another battery, and if it does not work, then you have a lesson to buy other phones in the future.